# Why does Traefik 2.0 not detect the default static certificates I have specified, and instead generate one itself?

Tags: https, docker-swarm, traefik

In my initial attempts to migrate a docker-swarm based Traefik installation from 1.7 to 2.0 I found that the default statically specified SSL config in my traefik.toml config file was being ignored, and with debug enabled my docker logs showed many similar messages:

```
time="2019-11-06T20:26:30Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
```

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that with Traefik 2.0 SSL config is always treated as dynamic (read carefully [here](https://docs.traefik.io/https/tls/)), and so one must define a dynamic file provider (see [here](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/providers/file/)), and furthermore this dynamic configuration must be in a file separate to the main Traefik configuration file.

If one tries to shortcut this process, and declare the main traefik config file as a dynamic file provider then one may see this non-helpful message in the logs:

```
time="2019-11-06T20:26:30Z" level=error msg="Cannot start the provider *file.Provider: template: :179:35: executing \"\" at <.Name>: can't evaluate field Name in type bool"
```

Once correctly configured messages will show like this instead:

```
time="2019-11-06T20:45:20Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider file: {\"http\":{},\"tcp\":{},\"tls\":{\"stores\":{\"default\":{\"defaultCertificate\":{\"certFile\":\"/etc/certs/server.crt\",\"keyFile\":\"/etc/certs/server.key\"}}}}}" providerName=file
```

Several posts on Containous's community forum (e.g. [here](https://community.containo.us/t/no-default-certificate-generating-one-even-if-default-certificate-is-specified/2219)) and Reddit (e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Traefik/comments/d5v9zh/syntax_for_multiple_middlewares_https_redirect/)) have definitely helped get to resolution here, but hopefully this summary helps also.

The following docker-compose.yml (manually edited to remove some abstractions, e.g. location constraints, networks, our own auth etc) is pretty much what works at this point to run Traefik as a scaled docker service on docker swarm, with the dashboard enabled and behind https.  The Traefik labels in this case are on the Traefik service itself, and set up a router and 'backend' service for the dashboard which is running on 8080.

```
version: '3.3'
secrets:
  rsa_private_key:
    file: key.pem
  rsa_cert:
    file: crt.pem
configs:
  toml_conf:
    file: traefik.toml
  dynamic_toml_conf:
    file: dynamic_conf.toml
services:
  svc:
    # The official v2.0 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.0.2
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      # Primary inbound HTTPS traffic.
      - "443:443"
      # HTTP traffic open for the purposes of permanent redirect to HTTPS.
      - "80:80"
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        delay: 30s
        window: 60s
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api-sec.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api-sec.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api-sec.tls.options=default"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api-sec.rule=Host(`myhost`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api-sec.service=api@internal"
        # Now the backend service...
        - "traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
    secrets:
      - source: rsa_private_key
        target: /etc/certs/server.key
      - source: rsa_cert
        target: /etc/certs/server.crt
    configs:
      - source: toml_conf
        target: /etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - source: dynamic_toml_conf
        target: /etc/dynamic_conf.toml
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```